# jquery offset().left issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, offset

While re-sizing the browser, i get the offset().left value of a DIV tag less by 1 at particular places and not on all places. This is only in Internet Explorer. Firefox and Chrome shows constant values.

```
var initPoint = $('#myMenuDIV').offset().left;

<div id="myMenuDIV">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="tabName">MenuItem01</div></td>
            <td><div class="tabName">MenuItem02</div></td>
            <td><div class="tabName">MenuItem03</div></td>
            <td><div class="tabName">MenuItem04</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

.tabName {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 105px;
}​
```

The div has a left margin. So when i re-size the browser, the div moves to left slowly. In firefox and chrome, the movement is constant. In Internet Explorer, it slightly moves right in the middle. So i get wrong value in offset. Is this a behavior of IE?

Comment: I have a table with one row and 6 Columns inside the DIV tag.

Comment: It is better if you include your code in the question.

Comment: Show your HTML and possibly try to reproduce that on something like http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related. But do you have a reset.css in your project?
reset.css overcomes the issue of having browser's default padding & spacing

See this link to a discussion on reset.css (or google it)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset